# Xamarin.Forms CustomRenderer for a TextCell

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am trying to a create custom renderer for the first time. All I want to do is change fontsize of a TextCell in a ListView.

I have looked at the guide here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/ for an entry cell but have no idea what to do for a TextCell and can't find the info anywhere (it is probably very basic but I am very new to Xamarin)

The code for the Entry cell is as follows (for Android)

```
public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
  // Override the OnElementChanged method so we can tweak this renderer post-initial setup
  protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
  {
    base.OnElementChanged (e));
    if (e.OldElement == null) {   // perform initial setup
      // lets get a reference to the native control
      var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText) Control;
      // do whatever you want to the textField here!
      nativeEditText.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.DarkGray);
    }
  }
}
```

So in the case of a TextCell what am I overriding? (if i use OnElementChanged, it doesn't give me the OnElementChanged for base - it does give me OnCellPropertyChanged but if I  use that for the method, then it seems to want PropertyChangedEventArgs then it doesn't like it --- I have no idea what to do, it is driving me nuts

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this should work. You can manipulate both the *Text* view as well as the *Detail* view of the `TextCell`.

I think you would be better off using a `ViewCell` though, since you can have more control over what is included and how it's rendered.

```c#
class MyTextCellRenderer : TextCellRenderer
{
    protected override View GetCellCore(Cell item, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var cell = (LinearLayout) base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        var textView = (TextView)(cell.GetChildAt(1) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(0);
        var detailView = (TextView)(cell.GetChildAt(1) as LinearLayout).GetChildAt(1);
        textView.TextSize = textView.DipsToPixels(32);
        return cell;
    }
}

public static class LayoutHelperExtensions
{
    public static int DipsToPixels(this View view, float dip)
    {
        return (int) Math.Round(TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, dip, view.Resources.DisplayMetrics));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply. I have tried to use your solution but I have a slight problem and due to my inexperience I need some advice

Comment: Scratch that - I got it working so Thankyou. You mentioned it would be better in a ViewCell, can you set me in the right direction - what do I need to use in the assembly (I have used ExportRenderer for the above example), what method do I need to override etc, or is there a good site that has this info in an easy to understand way? Cheers

Comment: Take a look at this article on how to use ViewCell. http://motzcod.es/post/93792500152/custom-listview-viewcells-in-xamarin-forms